# Strange unsolved PDO error: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have got an error in a `php` script:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 1 in /var/www/html/a.php:143

Pay attention it says near `''`(two single quotations).
This script used to work correctly on my previous server but when I moved to the new server, it kept showing this error. My PHP version is 7.0 and Mysql version is 5.7.22.

How I connected to mysql:

```
try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name", $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

It prints: "Connected successfully".
These are lines 142 and 143 which contain PDO queries:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT has_paid FROM info WHERE chat_id=".$chat_id);
$stmt->execute();
```

I visited similar questions but they didn't help.

How can I solve this?

Comment: i bet $chat_id is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your `$chat_id` is empty. So your SQL query ends up being:

```
SELECT has_paid FROM info WHERE chat_id=
```

MySQL syntax errors report the part of the SQL query that *follows* the place where MySQL got confused. In this case, it reports an error near `''` because it got confused at the end of the query. This is not surprising, because `=` requires a right-hand-side argument.

You should examine the code where you set `$chat_id` and make sure it has a non-empty value before attempting your query.

By the way, it seems strange to me that you're using `prepare()` and `execute()` but you're not using query parameters. You should code it this way:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT has_paid FROM info WHERE chat_id=?");
$stmt->execute([$chat_id]);
```

(There is no need to use `bindValue()` as some people will say.)

Comment: You don't NEED to use `bindValue`, I just find that it's easier to read in the long term, and it will certainly fix his SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: typo, missing `"`

Comment: To each their own. I like to pass an array to `execute()`. Often the values are already in an array, and it's convenient to pass the array instead of making a loop to run bindValue() on all its elements.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using prepared statements correctly and are opening yourself up to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Use something like this...

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT has_paid FROM info WHERE chat_id= :chat_id");
$stmt->bindValue(":chat_id", $chat_id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Your error is telling you exactly what's wrong. Your SQL query is invalid. It's not a problem with PHP or PDO. It's probably that `$chat_id` is an empty variable. In fact, I checked your SQL syntax. It's perfectly valid as long as a value is supplied for `$chat_id`.